# Counting distinct triangles that have integer-length sides

Tags: php, algorithm

### Problem:

> We are interested in triangles that have integer length sides, all of
>   which are between `minLength` and `maxLength`, inclusive. How many
>   such triangles are there? Two triangles differ if they have a
>   different collection of side lengths, ignoring order. Triangles with
>   side lengths {2,3,4} and {4,3,5} differ, but {2,3,4} and {4,2,3} do
>   not. We are only interested in proper triangles; the sum of the two
>   smallest sides of a proper triangle must be strictly greater than the
>   length of the biggest side.
>
> Create a class `TriCount` that contains a method `count` that is given
>   ints `minLength` and `maxLength` and returns the number of different
>   proper triangles whose sides all have lengths between `minLength` and
>   `maxLength`, inclusive. If there are more than 1,000,000,000, return
>   -1.

### My solution:

[image]

```
class Form{

    /**
     *@var array données utilisées par le formulaire
     */
    protected $data;
    /**
     *@var string  tag qui entoure les champs
     */
    public $surroud ='p';
    /**
     *@param array $data
     *@return string
     */
    public function __construct($data = array()){
        $this->data = $data;
    }
    /**
     *@param $html string
     *@return string
     */
    protected function surroud(string $html){
        return "<{$this->surroud}>".$html."</{$this->surroud}>";
    }
    /**
     *@param $index string
     *@return string
     */
    protected function getValue(string $index){
        return isset($this->data[$index]) ? $this->data[$index] : null;
    }
    /**
     *@param $name string
     *@return string
     */
    public function input(string $name){
        return $this->surroud("<label for='".$name."'>".$name.": </label><input type='text' name='".$name."' value='".$this->getValue($name)."'>");
    }
    /**
     *@return string
     */
    public function submit(){
        return $this->surroud("<button type='submit'>Envoyer</button>");
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

class FormController{

    /**
     *@return objet
     */
    public function registerI()
    {
        return new TriCount();
    }

    /**
     *@param $params array
     *@return integer
     */
    public function register(array $params)
    {

            //les champs sont remplis d'entier
            if(intval($params['min']) && intval($params['max'])){

                //instancier la classe pour le calcul des probabilités
                $inst = new TriCount();

                //appel de la methode qui calcul les probabilités
                $nbre = $inst->count($params['min'], $params['max']);

                return $nbre;

            }else{

                $message_erreur = "Vous devez remplir avec des entiers superieur à 0!";

                return $message_erreur;
            }

    }

}
```

---

```
<?php

/**
 *Class TriCount
 */

class  TriCount{

    /**
     *@var integer  minimum du tableau
     */
    private $minLength;

    /**
     *@var integer maximum du tableau
     */
    private $maxLength;

    /**
     *@var integer nombre de triangle possible
     */
    private $count;

    /**
     *@param $minLength integer
     *@param $maxLength integer
     *@return integer
     */
    public function count(int $minLength , int $maxLength ){

        //initialiser le compteur
        $count = 0;
        //3 boucles qui font varier le (i,j,k)
        // le script s'arrete si la condition n'est pas vérifiée
        for ($i = $minLength; $i <= $maxLength; $i++){

            for($j = $i ; $j <= $maxLength; $j++){

                for($k = $j ; $k <= $maxLength; $k++){
                    //condition: la somme des deux petits cotés du triangle superieur au troisieme coté
                    if( ($i + $j ) > $k ) {

                        $count++;

                    }else{

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //si le nombre de possibilité dépasse 1000000000
        if ($count <= 1000000000 ){

            return $count;

        }else {

            return -1;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's call the maximum and minimum side lengths \$l_{max}\$ and \$l_{min}\$

We can see that for a certain choice of `$i` and `$j`, we can directly calculate the number of choices for `$k` as \$min(i+j-j, l_{max}+1-j) = min(i, l_{max}+1-j)\$, which suggests that wee can remove the innermost loop.

Now we've got our hopes up, and we hope that the second loop can be removed in a similar fashion. For a fixed value of \$i\$, we know that \$i < l_{max} + 1 - j \iff j < l_{max} + 1 - i\$. We also have to take care of the cases where either sum has a negative number of terms. This way, the second loop can be written as two sums:

$$ \sum_{j = i}^{l_{max}-i}i = i\cdot \text{max}(0, l_{max}-2i+1)$$ 
$$ \sum_{j = \text{max}(a, l_{max}-i+1)}^{l_{max}}l_{max}+1-j = (l_{max} - \text{max}(i, l_{max}-i+1)+1)(l_{max}+1) - \sum_{j = \text{max}(i, l_{max}-i+1)}^{l_{max}}j$$
$$ = (l_{max} - \text{max}(i, l_{max}-i+1)+1)((l_{max}+1) - \frac{l_{max} + \text{max}(i, l_{max}-i+1)}{2})$$

This got a bit messy, but both are arithmetic sums, and can be calculated fairly easily. Now the entire calculation can be reduced to one loop. I wrote a python script to test it:

```
minL = 5
maxL = 25
total_ways = 0
for a in range(minL, maxL+1):
    right_terms = maxL-max(a, maxL-a+1)+1
    left_sum = a*max(0, maxL-2*a+1)
    right_sum = right_terms*(maxL+1) - right_terms*(maxL + max(a, maxL-a+1))//2
    total_ways += left_sum + right_sum
print(total_ways)
```

It produces identical output for all test cases I've found, and should be way faster. Please ask for any clarifications.

Comment: "max" and "min" should never be written in italics -- not as "English subscripts" and not as function names (like sin and cos, which are also never written in italics). In addition, in mathematics, * typically denotes convolution. Use a dot operator for product.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thanks for the feedback, I updated the equations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, first we assume that we take only integer number I tried the script but it does not respond to the probematique for example when we have (1,2) you have (112) (111) (222) so  result: 3 ; your script gives -1

Comment: For the python script, I noticed that I made a mistake. it should be `for a in range(minL, maxL+1)`. It does indeed produce the correct output then. Also note that `//` means integer division in python, and is not a comment.

Comment: Glad that it worked, good luck! If you need even more performance, it might be possible to remove the last loop, but I leave that challenge to a mathematician.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>                 for($k = $j ; $k <= $maxLength; $k++){
>                     //condition: la somme des deux petits cotés du triangle superieur au troisieme coté
>                     if( ($i + $j ) > $k ) {
>
>                         $count++;
>
>                     }else{
>
>                         break;
>                     }
>                 }
> ```

How can you do this without a loop?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>     //si le nombre de possibilité dépasse 1000000000
>     if ($count <= 1000000000 ){
>
>         return $count;
>
>     }else {
>
>         return -1;
>     }
> ```

I think the intention is that you should stop counting when you reach 1,000,000,000, and just return early at that point:

```
                //condition: la somme des deux petits cotés du triangle superieur au troisieme coté
                if( ($i + $j ) > $k ) {
                    $count++;
                    if ($count > 1000000000) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }else{
```

Comment: Yes, the condition should be in the loop, to stop the process